# Simulate PUT on a link, in Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, put

So far, I know that in Rails I can simulate a PUT request using a form which has a hidden input with `name='_method'` and `value='put'`, but I'm interested in simulating that for a link.

How can I have a link in a view that would fit this route:

```
match '/article/:id/publish', :to => 'article#publish', :via => :put
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs for link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) say you can specify a :method option that creates a form that is submitted on clicking the link.

```
link_to "Publish!", publish_article_path(article), :method => :put
```

Not sure what your route helper  method would be (I assumed `publish_article_path` - you should be able to figure it out with `rake routes` from the command line.  The `:method` is the important part that will do the magic you want.

Comment: ...only one remark: the `:method` option doesn't create a form anymore, but it adds a `data-method="put"` attribute to the link.

Comment: I didn't test this but in that case, it seems the Rails documentation is out of date! Good catch.

Comment: It's not out of date, checkout clearly: <a href='http://www.example.com' rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Destroy</a>

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, the example output they include is up to date (Even though that is `:delete` and not `:put`).  However, under the Options heading for `link_to`, it clearly states:

"`:method => symbol of HTTP verb` - This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified" - 
Which is clearly out of date.